# CBLite Replicator not re-syncing after purging documents

Tags: swift, swiftui, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

We have an iOS application using `Sync Gateway` and Couchbase Server to synchronize data between our mobile clients.

Now we have a use case  where we are syncing **Documents**, by  specifying `Channels` to replicator configuration. This first sync works fine and we can see replicator total progress.

```
 Master Data Replicator total progress is : 2

 Master Data Replicator completed progress is: 2

 Master Data Replicator status  is currently : busy

 Master Data Replicator status currently : stopped
```

In second use case there is a scenario where we have option to `delete` everything and `re-sync`. To achieve this we are `purging` all the saved documents locally which is also working fine.

But, when we are calling `replicator` again using same channels in configuration, the documents aren't syncing again. The logs looks like below -:

```
 Master Data Replicator total progress is : 0

 Master Data Replicator completed progress is: 0

 Master Data Replicator status  is currently : busy

 Master Data Replicator status  currently : stopped
```

What I tried is if i set reset `Checkpoint` to `true` for start **replicator** call it starts to re-sync, but I'm not sure if that's correct way to re-sync the purged documents.

Can anyone suggest, what's the right solution to re-sync purged docs? The `ReplicatorType` for our configuration is set to `.pull` only.

Answer (score 1):

Couchbase Lite sends a checkpoint to server to get the documents to the device. Purging the documents in device do not reset this. Your intuition is right. If you reset the check point, the documents will re-sync to the device.